# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Mac 2013 laptop, but stuck at flashing folder and cannot use it

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, usb, mac

I have a Macbook Pro laptop, Late 2013 edition, etc. I wish to wipe out OS X and put Ubuntu 14.04 on it, since I need 14.04 for my work.

So, I put Ubuntu 14.04 into an empty USB stick [following the instructions in this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0). Everything there seemed to work. Next, I booted from USB. I started my laptop and was given the starting installation screen instructions, e.g. [as shown in this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0). Again, things seem to work fine and I thought I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed.

Unfortunately, upon restarting [I get the flashing folder as described here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204323). Here's what happens with three other variations of starting the computer:

### **Attempt 1**

When I start without the USB stick there, and click CMD+R I get the globe icon. After a few minutes, I first went to the [Startup Disk following the instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204323). Unfortunately, nothing was there.

[image]

I then went to Disk Utility.

[image]

I am not sure how to interpret this screen. Note that disk0s2, disk0s3, disk0s4 are all grayed out. I *think* these were created from my Ubuntu installation attempt? (I actually did this installation twice, and in the second time I overrode my old installation, and before the second try, there was only disk0s2, disk0s3 listed.)

But I also see that disk0s2 has 465.57GB of capacity, whereas the disk0s3, disk0s4 have only 17.08 GB for each. Does this mean disk0s2 is where Ubuntu was installed?

[image]

There is also the OS X Base System but again I'm not sure how to interpret this and I would prefer OS X be completely wiped out so I can stick with Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

### **Attempt 2**

When I do the same as the previous method, except with the USB stick *in* there, then I see similar stuff, with the main difference being that Disk Utility now sees the flash disk:

[image]

Unfortunately, I still cannot figure out how to actually use Ubuntu 14.04 from this. The "Startup Disk" menu again shows nothing.

### **Attempt 3**

When I start it with my USB stick inserted but *don't* click CMD and R. Then I get to the GNU GRUB screen where it says "Try Ubuntu without installing", "Install Ubuntu", etc. But Ubuntu is *already* installed on this laptop.

[image]

(Sorry for the blurry quality.)

Does anyone have advice on how I can actually run Ubuntu 14.04 from my installation?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for the comment. Perhaps that would also work (haven't tried) but maybe this is another way. The questions are somewhat similar but they seem different enough, and I'm not sure if the questioner was running into the same problem as the user wasn't as detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting Ubuntu installed, it will pop a window telling you to restart the computer. **BEFORE** you do that, [follow the instructions in this guide to change the boot order](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy#Installation) so that Ubuntu is booted before Mac OS X.

That worked for me. Whew. (There are still many things you need to do to get Ubuntu working smoothly, but those are beyond the scope of this.)

Here's step #5 which was what I used.

> After installation, do NOT restart. We need to fix the EFI boot order information. Open a terminal, and type the following
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install efibootmgr 
>
> sudo efibootmgr
> ```
>
> You should see
>
> ```
>  "ubuntu" is listed as Boot0000*
> ```
>
> If you had booted into MacOS before installation, you should see two other boot entries,
>
> ```
> Boot0080*
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> BootFFFF*
> ```
>
> (these were created by MacOS), but the EFI BootOrder is
>   0080, which would make the laptop boot into MacOS only. To fix this, type
>
> ```
> sudo efibootmgr -o 0,80
> ```
>
> (If you had wiped out MacOS, then you only need to specify `0` instead of `0,80` in the command above.) Reboot (a command for reboot is `sudo reboot`).

Comment: @Zanna OK done.